# Create a legend based on numeric array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

There is an array filled with numbers from 1 to 5. Each number denotes a particular class.
What would be the best way to populate another array that converts this to a string array representing classes.

For example:

```
Numbers=[1; 2; 3; 3; 2; 1]
```

Answer should be:

```
Strings=['Apple'; 'Orange'; 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Orange'; 'Apple']
```

I understand doing this with a loop is a trivial thing. But does there exist a more elegant solution which does not use a loop in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to index your cell array of labels with your numbers:

```
Numbers = [1; 2; 3; 3; 2; 1]
Labels = {'Apple';'Orange';'Banana'};

Strings = Labels(Numbers);
```

Note that the result needs to be a cell array (not a matrix), because the strings have different lengths.

In your example, this gives:

```
>> Strings

Strings = 

    'Apple'
    'Orange'
    'Banana'
    'Banana'
    'Orange'
    'Apple'
```